# jquery form submit triggered by onchange not submitting

Tags: jquery, ajax, onchange

I have several forms on a single page, which all consist of 2 hidden elements and a checkbox. Upon changing the checkbox I want to submit the form via ajax and write to my database.

Form:

```
<form method="post" id="deadline_form<?php echo $aid; ?>" action="" style="width: 20px;" class="pull-left" >
    <input type="hidden" name="aid" value="<?php echo $act_array['activity']['aid']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
    <input class="deadline_on" type="checkbox" name="deadline_on" id="deadline_on" value="1" <?php if($deadline_checked){ echo "checked='checked'"; } ?> >
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.deadline_on').on('change', function(){
    var id=$(this).parent("form").attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        var id_complete = '#'+id;
    $(id_complete).submit(function(){
        console.log(id_complete);
        dataString = $(id_complete).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/activities/edit_deadline_preference",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){

            }
            });
        return false; //stop the actual form post !important!
    });
});
```

The everything until L5 of the JQuery (the submit) works, nothing works afterwards. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why on Earth do you find the ID of the form first (retrieving the form in process), then use this ID to look-up for the same form again? )

Comment: will you provide `/activities/edit_deadline_preference` php function

Comment: Could you please provide a reason for why you submit the form when the checkbox change??

Comment: First, I apologize, I'm having trouble understanding the dom hence not realizing I had the form, not just the ID of the form. Second, the checkbox submits a form because it's a simple preference to show or not show the activity's deadline for each user on their landing page (for time tracking/scheduling software). Tyvm suhail for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you don't need:`$(id_complete).submit(function(){`

This is enough:

```
$('.deadline_on').on('change', function(){        
    dataString = $(this).parent("form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/activities/edit_deadline_preference",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){    
            }
    });            
});
```